# Flag linked to a content, not to an user

Tags: flags

I have custom content "Character". Each user can add several Characters. 
I have another content type named "Item". Everyone can add several Item.

I want to create something like a "Whishlist" for characters, that means each user can link an item to a specific character to show that one specific character wants to have this item. This whishlist is not linked to an user but to a Character content this user created.

To create this relation, I thought about a Flag on items (like "Bookmark this !") but the flag is linked to an user, not to a content.
I have 2 solutions but i don't really like them. 
1-I can add a node reference in Character content to allow creator to search for Items. But i'd prefer to make it easier : when a user sees an item he wants to link to one of his character, he can directly link it on the item page.
2-I can also add a node reference on Item content to allow a user to search for the character he "owns" and add the item to his whishlist. But how can I limit the node reference to the content the user has created ?

Do you see other ways to do it ? 
how can I link a flag to a content but not an user ?

(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Mb better way is to grant user permission to edit character content and make reference field in chsracter for storing links to Item

Comment: Yes it works but it's not user friendly :( I'd like my user to be able to link an item to a character directly from the item page and in very few clics

Comment: It's interesting thing and If there is no solution for your problem - make your own.